# SQL Group Rows Based on Order and Key

Tags: sql, group-by, grouping

I have a table containing a set of temporary workers who's contracts can get renewed and they continue to work during an overlapping period or the worker could come back sometime later and work again for either a different department or the same one. My goal is to consolidate the data rows in such a way that if the workers time overlapped then in essence the overlapping periods can be converted into one row. If they don't then they should be represented as an individual row.

Current output:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|         Name        |    Department    |    Start Date    |     End Date     |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|         Tom         |     Finance      |    2010-08-09    |   2010-09-09     |
|         Tom         |     Finance      |    2010-09-10    |   2010-10-10     |
|         Tom         |        HR        |    2010-11-01    |   2011-01-15     |
|         Tom         |     Finance      |    2011-02-01    |   2011-03-01     |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Desired output

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|         Name        |    Department    |    Start Date    |     End Date     |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|         Tom         |     Finance      |    2010-08-09    |   2010-10-10     |
|         Tom         |        HR        |    2010-11-01    |   2011-01-15     |
|         Tom         |     Finance      |    2011-02-01    |   2011-03-01     |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I tried a to group by Name and Department and then outputting the MIN and MAX dates. However, this does not work for the example described above.

I also tried to rank the order however this function does not reset the rank number when the proceeding value does not match.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  Assuming the time frames in the table don't have gaps, the simplest method is probably the difference of row numbers:

```
select name, department, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by start_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name, department order by start_date) as seqnum_nd
      from t
     ) t
group by name, department, (seqnum - sequm_nd);
```

How this works is a bit tricky to explain.  However, if you look at the results of the subquery, you will probably see how the difference in the row numbers identifies the adjacent records with the same department.

If you have gaps -- and you want to take that into account -- then you can use a more refined version.  In this method, use `lag()` to get the previous end date and use that to create a flag to identify when "islands" start.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select name, department, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date - interval '1 day' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by name, department order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by name, department, grp;
```

Note that this uses date operators which are notoriously database-dependent.  The exactly syntax depends on the database you are using, so the code may need tweaking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, the data I have will have gaps and is expected to have gaps as they don't always overlap. Will this solution work if there are small gaps?

Comment: @user2582770 . . . The first solution combines adjacent rows with the same department, even if there is a gap.  The second splits at gaps.

Comment: Great this worked like a treat! I had a while loop going and hated it.

Comment: So one issue I faced with use this is that ROW_NUMBER is really slow when there are over a million records it needs to sort through. Any potential way to increase the performance?

Comment: @user2582770 . . . There is no `row_number()` in this answer so your question is unclear.  If you have a performance question, I would suggest that you ask a new question, provide a database tag, and an explain plan for the query.